# Null Or Multiple Parameters When Querying

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I have a stored procedure that has a parameter that must take a *comma delimited* varchar list of values that can be turned into a table of values or can be `NULL`, such as

```
@Values VARCHAR(10) = NULL
```

OR

```
@Values VARCHAR(10) = '1,5,10' 

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Parameters') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Parameters
CREATE TABLE #Parameters ( Id INT )

INSERT INTO #Parameters
SELECT
    [Value]
FROM
    FunctionThatReturnsStringToTable(',',@Values)
```

I need to figure out a way to make this work in SQL like so

```
SELECT
   SomeColumns
FROM
   TABLE
WHERE
   COLUMN = IIF(@Values IS NULL, COLUMN, (SELECT Id FROM #Parameters)
```

Which I know will not work. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the goal? Do you want to return all rows if the parameter is empty? Why are you using the #temp table? Can you show your function? Why aren't you using a TVP (so you don't have to use a split function to build a table that you're going to dump into a second table just to perform a join)?

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific about my intentions, that is my fault. If @Values is not passed in, then return everything. Otherwise, if  the parameter Values gets passed in (which is just a list of Ids) then search a column for those values (I know this normally looks like WHERE COLUMN IN (Select Values From #TempTable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, one way round it is this:

```
SELECT
  SomeColumns
FROM TABLE
WHERE
  ( @Values IS NULL )
OR
  COLUMN IN (SELECT Id FROM #Parameters)
```

As mentioned, you could avoid the temporary table by passing the parameters as a TVP, but only if the caller can do that also.

Or you could avoid it by in-lining the function call

```
SELECT
  SomeColumns
FROM TABLE
WHERE
  ( @Values IS NULL )
OR
  COLUMN IN (
    SELECT
      [Value]
    FROM FunctionThatReturnsStringToTable(',',@Values)
  )
```

Comment: This is actually the solution I wound up using. I know that I could use TVP, but I'm restricted by the requirements of the project (3rd party.) Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way (notice this avoids the unnecessary #temp table):

```
SELECT SomeColumns
FROM dbo.TABLE AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FunctionName(',',@Values) AS p
ON t.COLUMN = p.Value
WHERE t.COLUMN = CASE WHEN @Values IS NULL THEN t.COLUMN ELSE p.Value END;
```

But much, much, much better to pass @Values as a TVP instead of a string you have to split.

No idea what your split function actually looks like, but have a look at these posts:

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: Perfect. I knew that there was a solution to this, I was just brain dead at the moment. I also am restricted by the project to not be able to pass in the values as a TVP, otherwise I would. I'd upvote you if I could, however since I just registered I don't have the reputation for it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

To cut a long story short, if performance is a concern, you should test thoroughly because there are a few potential surprises. If you're lucky, the latest version of SQL Server may have resolved the issues I experienced.

---

[Aaron's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/70084/10426) is similar to what I used to do with with optional filter parameters. I.e.

```
WHERE Col1 = ISNULL(@Param, Col1)
  AND ...
```

Unfortunately I discovered that this played havoc with the optimisers ability to use an index on `Col1`.

This led to me using

```
IF @Param IS NULL
    SELECT  ...
    WHERE   ...
ELSE
    SELECT  ...
    WHERE   Col1 = COALESCE(@Param, Col1)
        AND ...
```

I then later learned that the problem gets a little worse...

If you put the above into a stored proc, then the first time you call the stored proc will determine how it is compiled. So if you call `exec MyProc NULL`, the stored proc will be optimised for the True branch of the condition. And may run inefficiently for the False branch.

The only solution at the time was to split this into 3 separate stored procs so each proc is compiled and optimised independently.

```
-- Main Proc
IF @ Param IS NULL
    exec Proc1
ELSE
    exec Proc2 @Param

--Proc1
SELECT  ...
WHERE   ...

--Proc2
SELECT  ...
WHERE   Col1 = COALESCE(@Param, Col1)
    AND ...
```

I know this is a horrible solution, but whether you need to go this far will depend on your performance concerns and whether using an index on that particular column is even relevant.

Comment: You can solve this (if it *does* turn out to be an issue) much easier using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the statement, rather than creating multiple statements or multiple procedures. Yes you pay the recompile cost each time, but unless the query is extremely more complex than this, this should be negligible. In fact I would bet using the function at all (especially if it's a multi-statement TVF) is much more costly than using a scan when the parameter list is populated and small. Note that my answer suggested abolishing the function entirely...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Correct, I should have mentioned the RECOMPILE option as another workaround. But still, it should be tested. It's not just about the complexity of the query, you also have to consider how often its called. Called often enough, it will push up CPU utilisation. Fortunately most database servers are more concerned about IO bottlenecks than CPU. Also, the time to recompile may be small, but small time repeated often enough can still prove expensive.

Comment: If recompiling this procedure pushes your server from 98% CPU to 99% CPU, then yes, maybe it's a problem. But you probably have many other, much more important problems. For individual queries the compile time should be minuscule, and since most systems are more concerned with individual response times for end users vs. aggregate amount of CPU used (end users don't give a crap about CPU utilization), it's probably valuable to avoid "the wrong plan." With your solution it's tedious if there is one nullable parameter. When there are 15? Yikes.

Comment: Also I did not mean to suggest that you should just turn on `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and not test the impact it has. Testing should be implicit in every single suggestion of any kind of change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this function :

```
GO
-- =============================================
-- Description: Splits comma separated numbers in a string to a table rows
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [usp_CsStringToTable]
(
    @IDs nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS 
@SplitValues TABLE  ( ID NVARCHAR(max) )
AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
    DECLARE @xml xml
    SET @xml = N'<root><v>' + replace(@IDs,',','</v><v>') + '</v></root>'

    INSERT INTO @SplitValues(ID)
    SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(v.value('.','nvarchar(max)')))
    FROM @xml.nodes('//root/v') as records(v)

    RETURN
END
```

and then call it in your code, like this :

```
DECLARE @csv nvarchar(100) = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'

SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE 
     (((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [dbo].[usp_CsStringToTable] (@csv)) = 0) OR
      ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [dbo].[usp_CsStringToTable] (@csv)) > 1 
        AND Id IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[usp_CsStringToTable] (@csv))))
```

Comment: If I understand the requirement right (return all rows if the parameter is empty), I'm not sure how this helps. All you've provided is a different split function that doesn't take a delimiter as input.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the requirements, I thought he was asking for a split function of some sort. But sure, my select statement didn't account for returning all rows for an empty string. I'll update that.